# operand size mismatch for `imul '

Tags: assembly, x86, att

although I use only longs for multiplication, Have no idea, why the `operand size is wrong`:

```
.type _square, @function
_square:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
subl $4, %esp #room for the local variable

movl 8(%ebp), %ecx #the first and only argument
movl $1, %eax

_finding_loop:
incl %eax
movl %eax, %ebx
imull %ebx, -4(%ebp) #storing the result in local var
cmpl -4(%ebp), %ecx #compare with the argument
je _found #epilogue and returning
jmp _finding_loop
```

Comment: You probably meant imull %ebx, storing the result takes an extra movl

Comment: i dont get it. The first operand should be with WHAT i want to multiply the %eax (e.g. i want to multiply with %ecx or %ebx) - that is the first operand. And the seconu I supposed to be to WHERE to store the result. If i am not mistaken. So what exactly do you mean?

Comment: AT&T syntax is upside down. The first operand is the source and the second operand is the destination. Intel: "The destination operand is a general-purpose register and the source operand is an
immediate value, a general-purpose register, or a memory location". You can't define memory (`-4(%ebp)`) as destination.

Comment: There is no imul instruction where the destination is memory -- so the last operand (the destination and first source) must be a register.  The first operand (second source) can be a register or memory.

Comment: imul's destination can only be memory when there's only one operand https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul

Comment: @phuclv: In the one-operand case, that operand is a source, not a destination.

Comment: @PeterCordes oops my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**That's a bogus error message.  It's not operand *size* that's the problem, it's that `imul`'s destination has to be a register.**  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/imul.  Only the *source* can optionally be memory.

(AT&T syntax is `op src, dst`, opposite of Intel's manuals which use Intel syntax.)

When you get an error that doesn't make sense, you should consult an ISA reference and make sure the instruction you want is actually encodeable: it's not unheard of for assemblers to print an error message that doesn't properly explain why an instruction can't be assembled.  But usually it's either an ambiguous operand-size or that the encoding you want doesn't exist.

Perhaps GAS internals treat a memory destination as having unknown or some random size, and nothing kicks in to imply a size for that operand the way it would for `add %reg, (mem)`.  Maybe *because* `imul` doesn't have a memory-destination form.

---

Keep your local variables in registers like a normal person.  You only need to spill a variable to a slot on the stack when you run out of registers.

EAX, ECX, and EDX are call-clobbered in the normal calling conventions so you can use them without saving/restoring.  (EBX is call-preserved so your function is already violating the calling convention by destroying its caller's EBX value.)

---

```
cmpl -4(%ebp), %ecx #compare with the argument
je _found #epilogue and returning
jmp _finding_loop
```

Never write a conditional branch *over* a `jmp`.  Instead do `jne top_of_loop` to either keep looping or fall through.

---

IDK what your loop is supposed to do.  You didn't initialize your memory destination.  Did you think it was going to store the result of `ebx*ebx` into memory?  If so, why copy EAX to EBX in the first place?

It looks like you're searching for the sqrt of a number, not just squaring a number, so the function name is weird.  If so, you probably want `jb` as your loop condition to keep looping while `x*x < target`, and sort out equal vs. above after the loop.  (In case the function is called with an arg that isn't a perfect square.)

```
.globl find_exact_sqrt
find_exact_sqrt:

    mov   4(%esp), %ecx    # target number
    mov   $1, %eax         # start searching from 2*2=4

.Lloop:       # file-local label, not exported in the symbol table
                         # do {
    inc   %eax
    mov   %eax, %edx
    imul  %edx, %edx       # eax squared
    cmp   %ecx, %edx
    jb    .Lloop         # }while(i*i < target); // unsigned

    ret
```

Comment: Thanks. I am learning just few days GAS as I switch from c. However, in the code above, I dont understand why you dont store tour base pointer - as I learnt function convenction like this: `pushl %ebp`\n`movl %esp, %ebp`\n`movl 8(%ebp), %ecx #target number`. You just get the target number from stack pointer 4(%esp), instead of base pointer 8(%ebp), why so? Is not better to hold base pointer for better orientation?

Comment: @Herdsman: Same reason compilers enable `-fomit-frame-pointer` at `-O1` and higher: performance.  No need to waste EBP holding a frame pointer.  And since my version doesn't need any stack space, it was just as simple for human readers to access the one arg via ESP in the stack slot just above the return address.  (I'd rather have used a calling convention with register args, e.g. GCC's 32-bit regparm.  Or better, x86-64 System V.  But I kept it compatible with the function in the question.)