# Error: operand size mismatch for `vpsubw`

Tags: c, assembly, avx2

The `vpsubw` AVX2 instruction is being used normally (the number of operands and the width of operands are not problematic), but the following error still occurs:

> Error: operand size mismatch for `vpsubw`

If all the instructions about `vpsubw` in the code are commented out, the error will still be reported, which is very strange.

`vpsubw     %ymm13,(%rsp),%ymm13        # f0[0]*g0[0]`
`vpsubw     %ymm9,%ymm1,%ymm9           # f0[0]*g0[1]`
`vpsubw     %ymm3,%ymm14,%ymm3          # f0[1]*g0[0]`
`vpsubw     %ymm10,%ymm2,%ymm10         # f0[1]*g0[1]`
`vpsubw     %ymm4,%ymm15,%ymm4          # f1[0]*g1[0]`
`vpsubw     %ymm11,%ymm5,%ymm11         # f1[0]*g1[1]`
`vpsubw     %ymm7,%ymm0,%ymm7           # f1[1]*g1[0]`
`vpsubw     %ymm12,%ymm6,%ymm12         # f1[1]*g1[1]`

I've tried multiple methods, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas?

I've tried commenting out all the `vpsubw` instructions, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Only the first operand can be memory.  GAS's error message isn't very helpful for `vpsubw     %ymm13,(%rsp),%ymm13`, but that's the problem.  (last operand in Intel syntax; https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/psubb:psubw:psubd).  Consider using intrinsics to let a C compiler make working  asm for you.

Comment: *I tried commenting out all the vpsubw commands, but it still doesn't work.* Well that makes no sense.  You still get an operand-size mismatch from some other instruction that isn't `vpsubw`?  In that case the rest of your code is also broken.  Or you used the wrong comment character; `;` is a statement separator so it would have no effect.

Comment: @Peter Cordes  Thanks！`vpsubw     %ymm13,(%rsp),%ymm13` Here is exactly the problem！The problem has been solved！

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [operand size mismatch for \`imul '](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58040975) - GAS prints the wrong error message when you use memory instead of a register for an operand that has to be a register.